# Binding the same parameter SQL to many placeholders

Tags: php, pdo

It would seem that's it's not possible to bind a single SQL parameter to more than one location in an SQL query.

I tried the following...

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE alias LIKE :search OR content LIKE :search");
$search = "%".$search."%";
```

...but received the warning "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number".

What's the recommended way to bind a single parameter to numerous parts of the query?

Comment: [It's documented](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) _You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on._  The solution is to use a different name the second time, or use `?` placeholders instead and bind the variable twice (or pass it twice to `execute()` in the param array)

Comment: I'm looking around for another question with a good answer - this is asked fairly often.

Comment: Thank you. I'm generally more of a front-end dev and the php docs are a little confusing to me at times. FWIW I did try searching for an answer, but I guess my lack of jargon know-how let me down.

Comment: It's difficult to find a good one - that's why I'm still looking... :)